# Wait for and/or kill process grandchildren produced by fork

Tags: c, fork, wait

I `fork()` into process X and Y, afterwards Y `forks()` again into itself and process Z multiple times.

Now process Y is some kind of "listener" and I would like X to be the deleter. The Z processes perform the actual actions. Z processes are grandchildren of X.

With a FIFO and some signaling, X has produced a list of all pids of the Z processes. The problem now is that I would like to delete Z process zombies with X (going through the list of pids).

I've tried it with `waitpid()`, but of course that doesn't work (it only does for direct children). But I've read about the possibility of making an extension yourself for this. But I really wouldn't know how to do it.

I've thought of the deleter keeping another list with zombies (signal when exiting) but this is just the same as i did with saving the pids, I would like to do it differently.

Does anybody have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

The only process that can acquire exit statuses from its distant Nth generation grand-children is the 'init' process, and that is a special case rule implemented by the kernel.

In general, a process can only wait for its direct children to die; it cannot wait for its children's progeny to die.

Morbid business...

---

If you're in charge of the process `Y` code, or can influence it, perhaps that process should set `signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN)` so that the `Z` processes do not create zombies.  Process `X` could even do that itself while it forks the `Y` processes by ignoring SIGCHILD in the child process after the `fork()` and before any `exec*()` of the `Y` process.  This only gets overridden if the `Y` processes explicitly set a different handler for SIGCHLD.  And if the `Y` code explicitly sets SIGCHLD handling and does not actually collect its zombies (`Z` processes), then you can report a bug in the `Y` code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported. If your sole intent is to prevent the 'Z' processes (i.e., the grandchildren) from turning into zombies, you can use [`setsid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsid). If you actually need their exit status, however, you really need to reap them from the 'Y' processes.

Answer (score 0):

Your question does a terrific job of making the actual problem hard to understand. Still, I believe I can discern the following: "I want to get rid of the zombies". Well, don't we all.

There are multiple ways of doing this:

- Have `Y` ignore `SIGCHLD`. `forked` children will not turn into zombies when they die
- Have `Y` periodically reap (`wait`) for any children

It's your choice which one you use, but it seems to me the first is what you want.